Does any first-order formula have a quantifier-free consequence?
In David Marker's "Model Thoery: An Introduction", the author gives a criteria for quantifier elimination by common substructure as Theorem 3.1.4.
In his proof, he defines a set $\Gamma(\overline{v})=\{\psi(\overline{v})：\psi \text{ is quantifier-free and } T \models\forall\overline{v}(\phi(\overline{v})\rightarrow\psi(\overline{v}))\}$, where $\phi(\overline{v})$ is some first-order formula.
And it seems that the set is always non-empty, and I wonder why.

Yes, $v_1=v_1$ is always in $\Gamma(\overline{v})$ (where $v_1$ is one of the variables in $\overline{v}$).

Note: Writing $v_1 = v_1$ is a bit of a hack here. It's just a way to find an explicit formula which is always true. Some presentations of first-order logic include logical constants $\top$ and $\bot$ ("true" and "false") which always evaluate to true and false, respectively. Then we could say that $\top\in \Gamma(\overline{v})$.
It turns out that the choice of whether to include $\top$ in the syntax actually matters when you try to run Marker's argument with a sentence $\varphi$ (so there are no free variables) in a language $L$ with no constants and no $0$-ary relations. Then $\Gamma$ should be the set of all quantifier-free sentences which are consequences of $\varphi$, but in a language with no constants and no $0$-ary relations, there are no quantifier-free sentences whatsoever! (...unless we include $\top$ and $\bot$ in our logic) This (and a related problem about empty structures) is why the statement of Theorem 3.1.4 in Marker assumes the language includes a constant symbol $c$.
